# Xslt: Get value of element by attribute name

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to get the value of element by element attribute
This is the xml

```
<root><parameters>
<parameter name="ArticleId">0</parameter>
<parameter name="KeywordsTitle">villas-boas-wants-more-respect-for-tottenham-over-bale-saga</parameter>
<parameter name="NewsTag" />
<parameter name="Sport">0</parameter>
<parameter name="BoxTitle" /><parameter name="BoxTitleUrl" />
</parameters></root>
```

How can I get the value of the parameter name **KeywordsTitle** in XSLT file

Please Advice,

Comment: <xsl:value-of select="//parameters/parameter[@name='KeywordsTitle'])"/>

Answer (score 0):

One way is.

```
<xsl:value-of select="root/parameters/titleparameter/@name="KeywordsTitle"/>
```

Ofc with

```
<xsl:template match="/">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/root/parameters/parameter[@name='KeywordsTitle']" />
```

to select from the root into the correct path, or you can do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="//parameter[@name='KeywordsTitle']" />
```

to scan the complete XML file to a `<parameter>` element